# How to implement animation on element when drop? Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to implement this animation - http://jsfiddle.net/Lgqrvwum/ when drop the image to container.

I have a recycle bin and grid of photos, when i drag one of photo to recycle bin container it should disappear and cause [smoke animation](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgqrvwum/).

```
$("#photo-grid").sortable({
        connectWith: ".trash",
        update: function (event, ui) {
          var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");
        },
        helper: "clone",
      });

      $(".trash").droppable({
        accept: "#photo-grid>img",
        hoverClass: "dropAreaHover",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
          ui.draggable.remove();
        },
      });
```

Comment: Your HTML code doesn't seem to have the recycle bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example was not complete. I create an example that is based on the following example: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

Consider the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qh3nmoL1/23/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
    <li>discard</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="trash" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
  <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Trash</h4>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#puff {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/wvPeK.png) no-repeat;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
}

#trash {
  float: right;
  width: 32%;
  min-height: 18em;
  padding: 1%;
}

#trash h4 {
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 0.4em;
}

#trash h4 .ui-icon {
  float: left;
}

#trash .gallery h5 {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function deleteImage($item) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      var $list = $("ul", $trash).length ?
        $("ul", $trash) :
        $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($trash);
    });
    $("<div>", {
        id: "puff",
        style: "display: none;"
      })
      .appendTo("body")
      .position({
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: $item
      })
      .fadeIn("fast")
      .delay(10)
      .fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $item.remove();
        $(this).remove();
      });
  }

  $("#gallery li").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: "document",
    cursor: "move"
  });

  $("#trash").droppable({
    accept: "ul > li",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      deleteImage(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

It was not clear why you would use your own animation function when there are lots to use in jQuery UI. As you're already planning use Drag and Drop, just use whats already there. There are also created to cascade and have built in callbacks so you can more easily chain events properly.